# Comando PHP Artisan não funciona

Tags: php, laravel, artisan

Teve uma demanda no trabalho em que tive que pegar um projeto Laravel 5 de um cliente e começar a alterar ele. Tive alguns problemas na hora de colocar para rodar, mas agora está indo, com exceção do comando `artisan`, que não funciona nem com quando digito `php artisan`.

Preciso fazer algumas alterações, como criar models e controllers, mas simplesmente dá sempre o erro

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException] Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed

Estou rodando o comando na pasta do projeto.

Comment: Provavelmente é um problema de incompatibilidade de versão do PHP com a do Laravel.Sabe informar a versão deles.

Comment: Qual laravel você usa? Qual versão? É sempre importante oferecer detalhes nas perguntas, para que possamos detectar o problema.

Comment: A do PHP é 5.5.12, e estou usando o Laravel 5

Comment: Mas outros projetos que tenho o artisan funciona, só nesse projeto que peguei de um cliente que está dando esse problema

Comment: Tá parecendo coisa de código antigo, hein. Esse sistema sempre foi em Laravel 5 ou ele está sendo migrado? Sabe em qual versão do php ele era rodada?

Comment: Tente desabilitar os erros no arquivo `artisan` para ver  se funciona. É uma gambiarra, mas vale a pena tentar. Faça isso na primeira linha do artisan (depois do <?php é claro)

Comment: Seu erro está relacioado a uma linha mais ou menos como essa `obj = & new Classe();` procure por um `&`. Eles não usariam um recurso deprecidado/removido ou gambiarra.

Comment: @rray talvez ele mesmo tenha codado isso então, né?

Comment: Você precisa adicionar mais detalhes a pergunta @IsaiasLima. O artisan não informa em qual arquivo ocorre o erro de execução?

Comment: Onde exatamente procurar o "&"?
Fiz um composer update, e apresentou o sequinte erro no artisan: "Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with an error [RuntimeException] Error Output: ". Daí mostra muitos comandos do artisan como "update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist]...

Comment: @IsaiasLima, faz o seguinte, tenta um `composer update no-scripts`. Se for, é que tem um script adicionado a execução no composer que está dando pau.

Comment: Acabei de tentar, mesmo assim não foi, deu o mesmo erro que passei acima

Comment: @IsaiasLima Eu não acho que esse erro esteja no LARAVEL, mas sim em alguma parte específica da aplicação como controllers, models, services etc. Tudo o que você deve fazer agora é procurar com ajuda do seu editor de código, IDE ou ferramentas de linha de comando do LINUX por algum padrão como isso: "&$". Isso porque o erro deriva de alguma chamada de função onde é passado algum parâmetro com "&" na frente da variável/parâmetro. Ache esses ocorrências e estará resolvido.

Comment: @felipsmartins descobri agora que o projeto foi feito em Linux, e estou tentando mexer nele no Windows... há algum problema em relação a essa condição? Já tive que fazer umas alterações para que o projeto funcionasse justamente por causa disso

Comment: @IsaiasLima Não, não há qualquer relação, pode ficar tranquilo quanto a isso. A única exceção é o cuidado com caminhos de arquivos ou fato de Linux ser case-sensitive quanto aos nomes de arquivos (mas isso não deveria ser problema, uma vez que você está usando windows no momento)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entenda o problema:

```
<?php 

function spam(&$arg) {
    print $arg . "\n";
}

$var = 'PHP';

spam(&$var); # Causa erro
spam($var); # Okay!
```

Eu não acho que esse erro esteja no próprio framework Laravel - pois alguém já o teria detectado -, mas sim em alguma parte específica da aplicação como controllers, models, services etc.

Tudo o que você deve fazer agora é procurar (com ajuda do seu editor de código, IDE ou ferramentas de linha de comando do LINUX) por algum padrão como isso: "`&$`" nas chamadas de funções (**mas não em definições**) do código fonte.
Isso porque o erro deriva de alguma chamada de função onde é passado algum parâmetro com "`&`" na frente da variável/parâmetro. Ache esses ocorrências e estará resolvido.

No editor **sublimetext** há uma ferramenta chamada Find in files, o menu é:
Find -> Find in Files... (Shift + Ctrl + F):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## EDIT

Eu reparei que você postou somente parte do erro.
Eu estou muito seguro que se você postar o restante da mensagem ou StackTrace (melhor) haverá a linha de onde está o erro e então você nem precisará procurar no código-fonte inteiro, apenas ir na linha apontada no erro e fazer o ajuste. Por favor, cole o stacktrace do erro.
É esperado que um  erro típico como esse retorne algo assim:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed in
>   /home/martins/teste.php on line 10
>
> Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed in
>   /home/martins/teste.php on line 10

Comment: Acabei de fazer isso, mas mostrou uma infinidade de arquivos, e alguns deles só com codificação estranha mostrando essa combinação "&$", além dos outros arquivos criados pelo próprio Laravel.
Comecei a fazer alterações em alguns arquivos e fiz um teste com "php artisan", e começou a dar erro no Timezone do arquivo Compiled.php, então voltei tudo como estava

Comment: No cmd do Windows só mostra o erro que eu passei. Tem algum log onde eu possa ver isso?

Comment: @IsaiasLima Não sou um desenvolvedor Laravel, mas acho que os logs podem ajudar muito, se não estou enganado os arquivos de logs ficam em: `storage/logs`

Comment: Boooooa, foi isso mesmo
Fui no log e apresentou erro no arquivo CheckJobs.php, linha 133, justamente essa combinação &$
Ajeitei aqui e funcionou perfeitamente
Valeu mesmo @felipsmartins